# HTML code: weird result

Tags: html, height, width

If I change the height of the upper orange box (the div with id = "here") from 100px to 100%, the box disappears. I don't understand why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 10%;  display: inline-block; border: solid black 1px">
    <center>
      <div id="here" style="width: 50%; height: 100px; border-top-left-radius: 30%; border-bottom-right-radius: 30%; background-color: orange;">
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div style="width:80%; height:70%; margin-left: 10%; background: #FFFFB8; display: inline-block;">
  </div>
  <center>
    <div style="width: 50%; height: 100px; border-top-left-radius: 30%; border-bottom-right-radius: 30%; background-color: orange;">
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side-note: `<center>` is not supported in html5.

Answer (score 0):

Your div with the id of "here" is wrapped in a center element. That element has a height of 0 unless you give it one, so give that element a height of 100%:

```
<center style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="here" style="width: 50%;height: 100%;border-top-left-radius: 30%;border-bottom-right-radius: 30%;background-color: orange;height: 100%;">
    </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center your div don't use center elements, remove them and instead add to target div style "margin: 0 auto;" - then your div#here will have his target height and your code will be more correct.